# td Width Not Working - NO CLUE Why

Tags: css

I have NO idea why this is giving me such a problem; I've made functioning tables a million times. Trying to make a full-width table.

The first cell should take up whatever space the other two fail to.
The second and third cell should each be 200px.

The goal is to not have a width attributed to the first cell so that it will change size as the window changes size - BUT even if I add a width attribute to all three (as it is in the below CSS), it doesn't space out correctly. It's cramming itself into the far right corner of the table, even though I've marked the table with a width of 100%.

PLEASE HELP!

```css
table.topper-table {
 width: 100%;
}

td.topper-table-nav {
 width: 65%;
 text-align: left;
}

td.topper-table-search {
 width: 10%;
 text-align: right;
   padding-right: 25px;
}

td.topper-table-social {
 width: 25%;
 text-align: right;
 border-left: 1px solid #9db3c4;
 padding-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<table class="topper-table">
<tr>
<td class="topper-table-nav">
TEST
</td>
<td class="topper-table-search">
TEST 2
</td>
<td class="topper-table-social">
TEST 3
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Its displaying as per the percentage in this snippet when i run it..

Comment: See my answer below without percentages.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the code you're targeting at, which does exactly what you try to achieve, both in Chrome and Firefox. I suppose you already tried something like this (not with the percentages as displayed above). Can you test my code and run it to see how it renders at your computer?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table.topper-table {
      width: 100%;
    }
    td.topper-table-nav {
      text-align: left;
      background-color: orange;
    }
    td.topper-table-search {
      width: 200px;
      text-align: right;
      padding-right: 25px;
      background-color: red;
    }
    td.topper-table-social {
      width: 200px;
      text-align: right;
      border-left: 1px solid #9db3c4;
      padding-left: 25px;
      background-color: lime;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table class="topper-table">
    <tr>
      <td class="topper-table-nav">TEST 1</td>
      <td class="topper-table-search">TEST 2</td>
      <td class="topper-table-social">TEST 3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```